# Changing a designer-generated Form's class

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2008, windows-forms-designer

I'd like to change a designer-generated Form's class from Form to a child class of Form.  This can be done in the .designer file.  The problem, of course, is the risk of the designer regenerating the code.

Is there a way to change the class via designer (without redoing everything), or is there a way to safely change the .designer file without risking it being overwritten?

From the .Designer.vb:

```
<Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.DesignerGenerated()> _
Partial Class frmReportSelection
    Inherits System.Windows.Forms.Form
    ' ...
End Class
```

Wanting to change this to `Inherits DerivedForm`

Comment: I just fired up an empty VS2012 WinForms project, and the parent class of the sample `Form1` class is specified in the `.cs`, not in the `.designer.cs` - has this changed since VS2008?

Comment: @millimoose - If so, it would have been between 2008 and 2010.  I can confirm it behaves the same way for 2010.

Comment: Could you explain what do you mean for child class? A code example is better

Comment: @Steve I'm reasonably sure he wants to have the designer-created form inherit from some other class than `System.Windows.Forms.Form` which is the default.

Comment: @millimoose Sorry I should've specified this as a VB project

Comment: Added more explanation / sample

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It really is as simple as clicking "Show All Files" in Solution Explorer, opening the `.Designer.vb` file and manually editing the `Inherits Form` to `Inherits FormChildClass`.

I did this with ~50 forms and had no problems with VS trying to override.